Google Play Console Violation: Invalid Data Safety Form - How to Resolve Discrepancies?
I recently received a violation notice from Google Play Console regarding the Data safety section of my app's listing. The details are as follows:
Violation:
Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy: Invalid Data safety form
Details:
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.
We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.
You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.
My Question:
How can I identify and resolve the discrepancies between my app's data safety form and its actual data collection and sharing practices? What steps should I take to ensure that my Data safety form is accurate and compliant with Google Play's User Data policy? Additionally, how can I check if any third-party SDKs in my app are collecting user data that needs to be disclosed?
Description:
I've been working on an app that is listed on Google Play, and recently, I received a violation notice related to the Data safety section of my app's listing. According to Google Play Console, there are discrepancies between the data safety form I filled out and the actual data collection and sharing practices of my app.
The violation notice indicates that my app transmits user data off the device, which I have not disclosed in the Data safety form. This includes data collected through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in my app. Google Play Console has provided some details about SDKs that may be responsible, but the list might not be exhaustive.
I need to understand the following:
How can I accurately determine what user data my app collects and shares?
What are the best practices for filling out the Data safety form in Play Console to ensure compliance?
How can I identify which third-party SDKs are collecting user data, and what data they are collecting?
What steps should I take to update my Data safety form to accurately reflect my app's data practices?
I would appreciate any advice or resources that can help me navigate this issue and ensure my app complies with Google Play's policies.
Thanks!

This question shows that you don't seem to understand how your app works and what it does. Start learning what depencies you use and check if they are really necessary. Normally good designed frameworks that collect user data provide templates for Google forms you need to fill out.
